# Asp.net ViewModel returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

I am fairly new to Asp.Net Mvc5 as well as c# and I am hoping to acquire a few pointers here, I have been trying to figure out why I was getting the following error :

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[SoccerTeams.Models.Player]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SoccerTeams.Models.ViewModels.TeamViewModel]'.

However now after debugging I realized that the ViewModel object is actually returning null values for all the items. I have created a page that works correctly for adding a team as well as players for that team. In my database the teams has one table and all the players are in another table which each player has the teams name with it (player and team name are in two separate columns) so it can be associated with the correct team. I have created a ViewModel and I am attempting to call that ViewModel and be able to return all the players to the view so I can show them in a list.

My Team controller for the "View all players view" is as follows:

```
 public ActionResult ViewAllPlayers()
 {
     TeamViewModel teamView = new TeamViewModel();

     return View(teamView);
 }
```

My Team Model is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace SoccerTeams.Models

{

    // This teams class will be used to represent the teams in the database
    public class Team
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string TeamName { get; set; }
        public string Coach { get; set; }
        public string Conference { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Player Model is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace SoccerTeams.Models
{
    public class Player
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid TeamId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My ViewModel is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace SoccerTeams.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class TeamViewModel
    {

        public string TeamName { get; set; }
        public string Coach { get; set; }
        public string Conference { get; set; }
        public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My CreateTeam action is as follows:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(TeamViewModel model, string addfiverows)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(addfiverows)) return View(model);
                var team = new Team { TeamName = model.TeamName, Coach = model.Coach, Conference = model.Conference };

                db.Teams.Add(team);
                var result = await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                if(result > 0)
                {
                    foreach(var player in model.Players)
                    {
                        var p = new Player { Name = player.Name, Id = team.Id };
                        db.Players.Add(p);
                    }
                    result = await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                if(result > 0) return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

My View I am trying to display on is as follows:

```
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}



@model SoccerTeams.Models.ViewModels.TeamViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View All Players";
}

<h2>View All Players</h2>


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TeamName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Players)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Players)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TeamName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Players)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

From researching I thought the problem had something to do with the @model `IEnumerable<SoccerTeams.Models.ViewModels.TeamViewModel>`. However after talking with @Tony Bao challenging my understanding I noticed that the Viewmodel is actually returning the fields however with null values.

I am also seeking any guides or tutorials as I am not only looking for a solution but also a better understanding of why this happens and how to use the ViewModel properly.

Comment: You are infact sending wrong model from your controller. Your controller sends Player list while your view expects List<TeamViewModel>. Sending the correct model from controller should resolve the issue

Comment: I tried doing what you said however it says TeamViewModel is a type, which is not valid in the given context. Could you possible give an example?

Comment: I tried "return View(TeamViewModel);" and the error above is what I got. I don't think I am doing it correctly.

Comment: If you want to return players for one team, then return View(model); @model SoccerTeams.Models.ViewModels.TeamViewModel (var item in Model.Players) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) ForEach should be player loop.

Comment: I want all Players for every team

Comment: Then you should have nested foreach loop, outer foreach for teams, inner foreach for players inside this team.

Comment: List<TeamViewModel> list = db.TeamViewModels; return View(list);

Comment: I will keep trying with your suggestions, as well I am updating my code in this post.

Comment: TeamViewModel is not part of the database. so I get an error. I have only added these two in the "IdentityModels" class                                      public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; } 
        public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }                                                                I am not sure if this is important for a ViewModel

Comment: I think I am starting to understand what is going on. I am passing the Players table from the database in the controller. That would be thee column of all player names and their team. Then I call @model to the Viewmodel I have created. Then in the view I am using forEach to go through the players. This is where my problem occurs.  The question is why. Thank you for your help you are getting me to see this in a different way.

Comment: Now I understand What is exactly happening, however I do not understand what the problem is still. I tried your implementation @Tony Bao, however they did not work wth the current architecture.

Comment: How to you fetch data and map to ViewModel ?

Comment: I am honestly not sure how to accomplish this? I have been looking online for an hour or 2 now on how to do this. I created an object of the viewmodel but I am not sure how to get the data in the Model. It returns null for all the parameters so I am clearly missing how to fill this properly.

Comment: From my current understanding it just grabs the methods with same name from the other models.

Comment: Could you please post your code ?

Comment: I have posted the TeamViewModel, the view and the controller. What else are you requiring? Id be happy to add it to the post

Comment: I have added team model and player model. Thank you for looking into this with me as I am unsure what I am missing.

Comment: You said you have 2 dbset, Team and Player. I want to know how do you get `Team` from dabatbase and map to viewmodel.

Comment: How are you populating Team and Player set? Based on your code you are initializing the view model object but never populating it's properties.

Comment: I have added the create team where it uses the team and player model to set in database. From my understanding Team and Player models gets the values from the database. I am assuming I am missing the "mapping to viewmodel" as it is null for the properties and I have not read anything on mapping. I apologize as my understanding is still fairly knew to these concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add `Player` collection to `Team` model:

```
public class Team
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public string Coach { get; set; }
    public string Conference { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

and in `Player` model add `Team`:

```
public class Player
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid TeamId { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team {get; set;}
}
```

and in `ViewAllPlayers` action:

```
public ActionResult ViewAllPlayers(Guid id)
{
    var team = db.Teams.Include(t => t.Players).Single(t => t.Id == id);
    TeamViewModel teamView = new TeamViewModel
    {
        TeamName = team.TeamName,
        Coach = team.Coach,
        Conference = team.Conference,
        Player = new List<Player>(team.Players)
    };

    return View(teamView);
}
```

Comment: Player = new List<PlayerModel>(team.Players), this gives me erros on Player and on PlayerModel

Comment: Perhaps you ment this?         Players = new List<Player>(team.Players)

Comment: I also have an error on == id. Id is in the table teams so I do not understand why it says it does not exist in the current context. Unless perhaps I need to drop the old database

Comment: It says it is not part of the context. Everything is getting brought except for the players. not passing the right id i think.

Answer (score 2):

You can view DisplayFor Templates in your scenario. There are tons of materials on displaytemplates(for display) and editortempates(for insert and update). you can search on google

Here what i will propose

```
     public ActionResult ViewAllPlayers()
     {  
        //this should be from your database

        var teamviewer = new TeamViewModel();
        teamviewer.TeamName = "t1";
        teamviewer.Players = new List<Player>() { new Player { PlayerName = "p1" }, new Player { PlayerName = "p2" } };          
        return View();
     }
```

Your view Models

```
   public class TeamViewModel
   {    
        public string TeamName { get; set; }
        public string Coach { get; set; }
        public string Conference { get; set; }
        public List<Player> Players { get; set; }      
   }   

    public class Player
    {    
        public string PlayerName { get; set; }          
    }
```

Create a Displayfor template here

```
Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Player.cshtml
```

Player.cshtml

```
@model SoccerTeams.Models.Player

@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.PlayerName)
```

On your index page

```
@model SoccerTeams.Models.TeamViewModel
<h2>View All Players</h2>


<table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.TeamName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>modelItem.Players)
            </td>
        </tr>      
</table>
```